# Speed and accuracy of text entry methods on smart phones?

Tags: mobile-text-entry, predictive-text

Are there any comparisons between the different text entry methods within the restricted interface size afforded by a smart phone.

Specifically between T9 predictive text, on-screen keyboard with auto-correct and Swype and looking at tasks like text messaging or Facebook status / commenting, i.e. small, informal, personal communications that many users perform daily.

Comment: "Which method is best" = that's not really answerable here. Can you narrow the question down a bit, perhaps?

Comment: This question would be much clearer and more useful if you simply deleted the first sentence of the last paragraph.

Comment: Also, you haven't stated your measurement criteria. What do you mean 'better'? What method is faster? What method is the most accurate? Which method suits long periods of writing compared to short text messages? Which method do users feel is easier to learn? Which method do users prefer...? We can't just say one is better than another without having some definition of what to measure against. It's just subjective otherwise.

Comment: Edited to ask for studies that compare only

Comment: It's still not clear what it is you're wanting measured. Ability to complete tasks... Accurately? Quickly? Easily? What sort of tasks - long emails? short text-messages? A better question would be 'Do T9 keyboards allow faster composition of long emails compared to Swype?'

Comment: Ideally I'm wanting to see information on many different measurements, would more than one question be appropriate? (I'm still learning this site, so be gentle!)

Comment: @ColinSharpe each question asked needs to be separate as there can only be one correct answer - if you ask two questions in one post and someone answers only question 'a' and someone else only answers question 'b' which one would you mark as the 'correct' answer? Provided each question is separate, is based on an actual problem that you currently have that you need a solution to then you can ask them separately - perhaps link to your other question if it's related, but they all need to be unique and separately answerable.

Comment: Ok well this is now much more specific, though I will also ask about other things to do with this subject

Comment: Is this question just dead then ?

Comment: This question had been added to the re-open queue when you edited it, however several users reviewed it and all agreed it was not suitable for re-opening. Now that it has been edited again it will be back on the re-open queue for other people to review. Please don't re-ask the same question just because this one has been closed, let the reviewing process take care of it as that's what it has been designed for.

Comment: So if I edit it again it will go into the re-open queue? There is a good question in here and I am determined to have it opened for answers! Unfortunately I got no notification a decision had been made and I also know closing is automatic after five days, plus I did comment to try and find out what had happened. It appeared to me that it had been forgotten.

Comment: I've never seen research on Swype. However, comparisons of text entry on mobile devices have been around as long as there have been mobile devices. Check out [this paper](http://www.yorku.ca/mack/mhci2013g.html) as a starting point for pulling the thread on this research. MacKenzie has been in this field for years. Check the references in his papers to find other papers you should read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a real relevance for [T9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T9_%28predictive_text%29) on a smartphone because the base reason for its existence doesn't exist on a smartphone. Secondly, there are many methods used for auto-correction on smartphones. As you noted, some do attempt to complete words based on what's already typed. Other's take the context of the word into account and some take common typos ("fat fingers") into account as well.

I'm pretty sure if T9 was good on a smartphone, the original inventor would have carried it over. Instead, he created [Swype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swype).